# How to add Foreign Keys to Django Field History?

Tags: django

I'm trying to track Foreign Keys using django-field-history, but when I add it, it does additional queries on every page using the Model

For example

```py
from field_history.tracker import FieldHistoryTracker

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user)
    field_history = FieldHistoryTracker(['user'])
```

will always give more queries on pages using Author, like so

```
SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = '2'
  1239 similar queries.   Duplicated 1235 times.
```

I've tried using user_id instead of user in Field History Tracker, but it will always return None. Using user.id or anything like it just returns an error.

I really need to keep that history data, but not at the cost of thousands of additional queries.

Also, would really enjoy keeping django-field-history as my whole DB is using it, but I'm aware I might have to switch package, and if so, which one would you advise ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, you are trying to log which user has updated, for this you should use `_field_history_user` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-field-history#storing-which-user-changed-the-field).
For example:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    field_history = FieldHistoryTracker(['name'])

    @property
    def _field_history_user(self):
        return self.updated_by
```

It would always update which user has updated the row for this table.

Comment: Maybe my example wasn't the best. My field user isn't the one who updated, but an editable field. Let's say I put my Author 1 to User 1, then switch it to User 2, then back to User 3, I want to see all the changes in my tracker